# Table Header with fixed header without using div

Tags: html, css

I want table header with fixed width without using div tag outside table. I need some solution in which i just need to change css file only. i have tried by putting table in side div with style:

```
width:100%;overflow-x:scroll
```

and on minimizing the browser's height and width, it is working fine.

But this is not what i want. I want to change in css style only, to avoid change in all the jsp files in my project

PSB my code:

**CSS**

```
h3 {
    font: bold 1.2em Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    background: #B7BBD6;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    clear: both;
}
.list {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    color: #000099;
    border: 1px solid #DEDFDE;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
    overflow-x: scroll
}
.list th, .list td {
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #B7BBD6
}
.even {
    background: #F1F1F1
}
/*.odd {background: #F1F1F1}*/
.odd {
    background: #FFF
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h3>Test Table</h3>

<table class="list">
        <tr>
            <th>a</th>
            <th>b</th>
            <th>c</th>
            <th>d</th>
            <th>e</th>
            <th>f</th>
            <th>g</th>
            <th>h</th>
            <th>i</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td>98052826</a></td>
            <td>Company</td>
            <td>asdfsafdsa</td>
            <td>asdfsadf</td>
            <td>asdfsafs</td>
            <td>sadfsaf</td>
            <td>1234</td>
            <td>asfsdf</td>
            <td>asfsafdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td>234568992</a></td>
            <td>Private</td>
            <td>asfsdfaf</td>
            <td>asfsaf</td>
            <td>safsdafsdf</td>
            <td>Some address</td>
            <td>3344</td>
            <td>&safsdafsda</td>
            <td>sadfsaddfdaf</td>
        </tr>
<table>
```

Please suggest??

Comment: You might want to look into the tags `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` and `<tbody>`, which can be declared inside a table (note that `<tfoot>` needs to be declared before `<tbody>` as per W3C standards).

Answer (score 0):

Set the following to your css stylesheet:

```
table{width: 100%;table-layout: fixed;}
```

**Edit**

If you could use jQuery, its easy:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/*define table class then place your class here instead of 'table'*/
   var tablewidth =  $('table').width();
   /*define h3 class then place your class here instead of 'h3'*/
    $('h3').css('width',tablewidth - 10);
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wyAT9/3/)

Comment: thanks for the solution.. but this makes my data overlap and i dont want this.. what i want is to have the scroll with fixed width.

Comment: if there is any solution for this, can u please tell me as it is on urgent basis. thanks..

Comment: what i want is to have <h3>Test Table</h3> with the same width as of table when i minimize my browser.

Comment: now the content is not overlapping but my requirement is to have <h3>Test Table</h3> with the same width as of table and also table content should be visible with scroll... thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
h3{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%
  }
  table{
    top:60px;
    position:relative;
  }
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/ijufum/4/edit)

Comment: thanks for the solution.. but this makes my data overlap and i dont want this.. what i want is to have the scroll with fixed width

Comment: what i want is to have <h3>Test Table</h3> with the same width as of table when i minimize my browser.

Comment: $(window).resize(function(){
   a = $('table.list').width();
  $('h3').css('width', a);
});

// you can try to add this by jquery to header of page, in the document.ready block. And remove property width:100% of css for h3 tag.